# Invalid callback error during call to node-fs-extra function copySync()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting an error when I try to use the copySync() function of the Node.js module [node-fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra). I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is the code I am using:

```
fse = require('node-fs-extra');

function deploy(done) {
    try {
        fse.copySync('dir1', 'dir2');
        console.log('fse.copySync worked!')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('fse.copySync threw an error');
        console.log(err);
    }

    done();
}
```

When this function is run I get this output:

```
fse.copySync threw an error
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
    at maybeCallback (fs.js:145:9)
    at Object.exists (fs.js:212:3)
    at Object.copySync (/var/www/html/dev/plugin-biblica-online-bible/node_modules/node-fs-extra/lib/copy.js:62:23)
    at deployPlugin (/var/www/html/dev/plugin-biblica-online-bible/gulpfile.js:134:13)
    at deploy-plugin (/var/www/html/dev/plugin-biblica-online-bible/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:427:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:440:12)
    at asyncRunner (/var/www/html/dev/plugin-biblica-online-bible/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}
```

It looks like it is complaining about a missing callback function. But according to [node-fs-extra documentation](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/copy-sync.md) the copySync() function does not accept a callback function.

I don't see errors when using other synchronous function like renameSync() and I can copy the directory fine using the asynchronous function:

```
fse = require('node-fs-extra');

function deploy(done) {
    fse.copy('dir1', 'dir2', {}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('fse.copy threw an error');
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('fse.copy worked!')
    });

  done();
}
```

Results in:

```
fse.copy worked!
```

In case it matters, the deploy() function is being run as a Gulp task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using [`node-fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fs-extra), which is deprecated. You're reading the docs for the package named [`fs-extra`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra).

Install `fs-extra`, then use:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra'); // do this instead of require('node-fs-extra');
// ...
```

Then, your code works.